# Placement of Submenu in Elementor Website

Tags: html, css, elementor

I am trying to create vertical navigation with a horizontal submenu on a website using Elementor. I have managed to do it partly, but I am not able to get the position of the submenu right. I want the submenu to be showing beside the tab (as marked in the pic)

Also, I want the arrow to be aligned centered with the text. Here is the code that I have used to get the output.

```
@media all and (min-width:767px){
selector{
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
transform: scale(-1);
}

selector .sub-menu {
transform: rotate(90deg);
position: absolute;
  }
}
```

Any help with this is appreciated. I am a newbie at this stuff and got the code built using research. I am using Elementor, and it is updated to the latest version.

Comment: add `position:relative` on `.sub-menu`'s parent .then adjust top property

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I didn't understand the comment "adjust top property" I added the position: relative to the code. This is what it looks like.

`@media all and (min-width:767px){
selector{
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
transform: scale(-1);
position:relative;
}

selector .sub-menu {
transform: rotate(90deg);
position:absolute;
  }
}`

Comment: I tried adjusting the top property but didn't work. Not sure if I am doing it right. This is what the code looks like now. `@media all and (min-width:767px){ selector{ writing-mode: vertical-rl; transform: scale(-1); position:relative; }  selector .sub-menu { transform: rotate(90deg); position:absolute; top:40em;  } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the final code that helped me to achieve what I was looking for.

```
@media all and (min-width:767px){
selector{
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
transform: scale(-1);
position:relative;
}

selector .sub-menu {
transform: rotate(90deg);
position:fixed;
margin-right: 70px;
transform-origin: top right;
  }
}
```